# Transaction simulation with preapply fails while injection finish successfully

Tags: transactions, rpc, operation, tezos-signer, inject

I'm trying to simulate an operation (transaction) before injecting it.
The run_operation endpoint return:

```
{ status: 'applied',
  storage: { prim: 'Pair', args: [ [Object], [] ] },
  big_map_diff:
   [ { action: 'update',
       big_map: '2265',
       key_hash: 'exprtfKNhZ1G8vMscchFjt1G1qww2P93VTLHMuhyThVYygZLdnRev2',
       key: [Object],
       value: [Object] },
     { action: 'update',
       big_map: '2264',
       key_hash: 'exprtfKNhZ1G8vMscchFjt1G1qww2P93VTLHMuhyThVYygZLdnRev2',
       key: [Object],
       value: [Object] },
     { action: 'update',
       big_map: '2264',
       key_hash: 'expruMJ3MpDTTKCd3jWWGN1ubrFT3y3qbZRQ8QyfAa1X2JWQPS6knk',
       key: [Object],
       value: [Object] } ],
  consumed_gas: '250176',
  storage_size: '9313' }
```

But the preapply endpoint return:

```
[ { kind: 'permanent',
    id: 'proto.005-PsBabyM1.operation.invalid_signature' } ]
```

The data sent in the preapply request:

```
[
{
  "protocol": "PsBabyM1eUXZseaJdmXFApDSBqj8YBfwELoxZHHW77EMcAbbwAS",
  "branch": "BMPm3eXWf8Qwxo43FD5EF4SKY1hoBbBvVCAhMEYNdvtNWZbvtrt",
  "contents": [
    {
      "kind": "transaction",
      "source": "tz1X3xW1EcS48RQXSdrDTF6xESm933eq251f",
      "fee": "30000",
      "counter": "376002",
      "gas_limit": "260000",
      "storage_limit": "10000",
      "amount": "0",
      "destination": "KT1MoY3KGe9qfLmtMJ8ubLZ5fxjMT7umKFyt",
      "parameters": {
        "entrypoint": "transferFeeless",
        "value": {
          "args": [
            {
              "args": [
                {
                  "args": [
                    {
                      "args": [
                        {
                          "args": [
                            {
                              "args": [
                                {
                                  "int": "20"
                                },
                                {
                                  "bytes": "dd55d03f0f39b355284a81401211a168f98f1cda89603b48e26adffd7ccd14356c0085ef0c18b31983603d978a152de4cd61803db881c0cf24a9a20ee0a712a09c0100019103c0aa2e81e0127a5a71a9312e66820b63ed6f00ffff087472616e73666572000000580707070700140100000024747a31587243767669483843716f484d534b704b757a6e4c4172456131795239553765700100000024747a3158764d425248776d58745853324b3658595a646d6363356b647742395354464a75"
                                }
                              ],
                              "prim": "Pair"
                            },
                            {
                              "string": "tz1XrCvviH8CqoHMSKpKuznLArEa1yR9U7ep"
                            }
                          ],
                          "prim": "Pair"
                        },
                        {
                          "string": "edpkvNYwBeVWcrn3SS55mUyi8qBiTZdQbzDgkRpW65xLG2W2c7aA6u"
                        }
                      ],
                      "prim": "Pair"
                    },
                    {
                      "int": "8"
                    }
                  ],
                  "prim": "Pair"
                },
                {
                  "string": "edsigtzYUgQ15JKRqtJdwpu3sZcLQ1E4E5LHHLhmYYDkRCjeMhzxiwG7nQMvghvWH8NkdujrBUStnSBSHbYubNwJR3mLFyvntXY"
                }
              ],
              "prim": "Pair"
            },
            {
              "string": "tz1XvMBRHwmXtXS2K6XYZdmcc5kdwB9STFJu"
            }
          ],
          "prim": "Pair"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "signature": "edsigtdzCuzKp1pYWt2q6FHb3o4ofoRnAXutCBv3bPm3sgXV6UfBdhDa2NQJivSMnZZvSvEM2qMzkqZyL3FaCHzYgriDrPG2kyy"
}
]
```

And the strange thing about this that the transaction can be successfully injected in the blockchain.

> This is a transaction hash for the operation: [oodLpS9sGkGGdpWvoEPL5vm6BcJvVeVuDLMAmnWdEzXSv1q7F1N](https://babylon.tzkt.io/oodLpS9sGkGGdpWvoEPL5vm6BcJvVeVuDLMAmnWdEzXSv1q7F1N), as you see in the tzkt explorer, the status is APPLIED

Request content in the run_operation and preapply are the same, the signature is valid since the transaction injected with success but I can't explain what's the problem with the preapply.

Does anyone have had this type of problems? Any help?

Thanks in advance.